# After a vendor update the Login from FosuserBundle returns Call to a member function has() on nu

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

in Januar I have the similar problem, and actually I'm wondering why the problem comes again:
It's a symfony 2.8 project, and I'm using the fosuserbundle, in the config.json is the version

```
"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.1",
```

So its not a dev-Version. On 5th Januar I make a vendor update - all works fine.
Yesterday i make an vendor update, and on calling the /login I got

Call to a member function has() on null
at 
[path_to_my_project] /vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php line 184

I have tested to downgrade the fosuserbundle, but that does not help. I assume, it has to with some update on the symfony sources after the 5th Janaur 2018.

Has somebody acutally the same problem?

Cheers
Thomas

Answer (score 1):

For those, who has the similar problem: It seems it has to do with some changes from 
`"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "2.0.2"` to `"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "2.1.0"`.

So i write in the composer.json the Version 2.0.2 until i find exactly, why this problem occurs.